# I have some problems I have to make a graph with Kibana when I add a division with my field I have no result

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, watch

/* excuse my english i'm french my split is nginx.access.response_code.keyword
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

*/

```
{
      "aggs": {
        "2": {
          "significant_terms": {
            "field": "nginx.access.response_code.keyword",  
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "3": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "fixed_interval": "12h",
                "time_zone": "Europe/Paris",
                "min_doc_count": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 0,
      "stored_fields": [
        "*"
      ],
      "script_fields": {},
      "docvalue_fields": [
        {
          "field": "@timestamp",
          "format": "date_time"
        },
        {
          "field": "event.created",
          "format": "date_time"
        },
        {
          "field": "read_timestamp",
          "format": "date_time"
        }
      ],
      "_source": {
        "excludes": []
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [],
          "filter": [
            {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2020-11-07T14:57:01.503Z",
                  "lte": "2020-12-07T14:57:01.503Z",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "nginx.access.response_code.keyword": {
                  "query": "200"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "nginx.access.response_code.keyword": {
                  "query": "301"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "nginx.access.response_code.keyword": {
                  "query": "304"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
/* the result my buckets are empty */

{
  "took": 302,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 11,
    "successful": 11,
    "skipped": 10,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6418480,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "2": {
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. it did not exist in my data nginx.access.response_code.keyword. Be careful, Kibana does not show you your error.